# How to initialize ng-model of input checkboxes in an ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, coffeescript

I've run into an issue when creating multiple [input[checkbox]es](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) for a list of items in angular with `ng-repeat` and attaching an `ng-model`:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items"> 
  <a ng-href="#/{{item.id}}" > {{ item.id }} </a>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedMessages[item.id]"/>
</li>
```

The issue here is that `selectedMessages[item.id]` is only **initialized** and set when the checkbox is **clicked once**.

**The reason this is necessary is that I would like to toggle all checkboxes with a single comand like so:**

```
$scope.toggleCheckboxes = (state) ->
  for key, val of $scope.selectedMessages
    $scope.selectedMessages[key] = state  # true or false
```

Let's say I have 3 checkboxes, and click 1 once, 2 twice, and 3 never, then said object will look like this:

```
$scope.selectedMessages = {
    "1" : true,
    "2" : false
  }
```

So obviously, `$scope.toggleCheckboxes(true)` will only work for those checkboxes.

**Is there a good way to initialize this ng-model for multiple checkboxes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` to populate the array. I used `$index` rather than making up a bunch of data with `id` properties...adjust your code accordingly

```
<input type="checkbox" 
     ng-model="selectedMessages[$index]"
     ng-init="selectedMessages[$index]=selectedMessages[$index]||false" />
```

JS

```
  $scope.selectedMessages=[];
  $scope.checkAll=function(){
    var msgs = $scope.selectedMessages
    msgs.forEach(function(elem, idx){
      msgs[idx] =true
    })
  }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/lkY8BOeemDT3sIVfnVtA)**</kbd>